# Limit of product of matrices with spectral radius less than 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, spectral-radius

If spectral radius of a square matrix $A$ is less than 1, then we know that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k = 0.$$

Now, I want to know whether we can also conclude the following results?
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k (A^{T})^k = 0$$
where $A^{T}$ is the transpose of matrix $A$.

Comment: Finite sum and products of sequences that tend to zero, tends to zero. And $(A^T)^k=(A^k)^T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $A^T$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$. Then use algebraic limit rules.